# Output Results of Table to .CSV BTEQ/FastLoad

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table full of data called "MYTABLE" I used `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;`

How do I output the results of this table to a .csv file for a Teradata database?

Comment: What is your source and destination database platform? Teradata provides utilities that allow you to extract and load data. (FastExport, FastLoad, and MultiLoad)

Comment: Source DB: DB1, Destination: DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible options using native Teradata utilities:

If you use the Teradata FastExport utility and specify the MLSCRIPT option in the EXPORT command a MultiLoad Script will be generated automatically that can be used to load the data file into Teradata. With a little tweaking you can point it at another system and load the data.

Teradata's ARC utility can be used to backup the data and then using the COPY facility in ARC put the data on a separate system.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ETL tool. Try [this forum](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/enterprise/regarding-data-extraction) for a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small table (approx 1000 records), you can turn on the Import/Export mode in SQL Assistant. This will help you to export the table as a csv (you can set the Tools-> Options -> Import/Export) and then import the file to your db.

While importing, you can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

The number of ? should be same as the number of columns in the table/file.

If it's a bigger table, Fastexport the data and the import it using Fastload/Multiload.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular export command in bteq. If it's a fast system, you can get a million rows in a few minutes but if slow, you might want to go with a different application or limit yourself to 100K rows.

```
.export file=myfile.csv
sel col1||','||col2||','||col3(title'') from mytable;
.export reset
```